# How to identify who initiated shared flyout in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a shared Flyout defined as a Page resource. The flyout is referenced and shared by several UI buttons on the page. When the user initiates the flyout from one of these buttons it brings up a short data entry form with an OK button. When the user activates the OK button click, in the code-behind handler, I need to identify which of the buttons initiated the flyout. How is this done. I'm thinking I need to use the handler parameters to walk my way to this reference.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="PlayerInfo">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Enter Player Name:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="PlayerName" />
            <TextBlock Text="Enter Credits:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="Credits" />
            <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="OKButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>

<Button x:Name="LeftPlayer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Players[0], Mode=TwoWay}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="36"
        ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click Here To Add Yourself" Flyout="{StaticResource PlayerInfo}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Players[who (which button) entered info] = PlayerName.Text;
    }
```

I just need to figure out which button initiated the shared flyout, so I can assign the gathered information back into my viewmodel.

Comment: Not sure what's going on here? Is the question too simple for a response, too difficult, or what? Seems like I even lost the guy who wanted me to post code, so he could better help. Don't even see his reply anymore. Looking like a waste of time, at least in this case.

Comment: As a workround, we can add Click event to LeftPlayer `Button` and in code behind get the LeftPlayer.Content to a global c. That we can use that variable in the OKButton_Click event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jayden. I have avoided using a global for the OK handler to check because it feels like a kludge and impairs readability. But it would work, and I thank you for the suggestion.